# HTML password box if/then redirect

Tags: javascript, html, passwords

Need lil bit of help if you may.
I'm trying to build a password form for my test website where you just get a password box on front page.

So I've built this:

```
<div class="inputcontent">
    <input type="password" id="password">
</div>
<div class="buttons">
    <input type="submit" style="display: none" .click()="myFunction">
</div>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var passwd = document.getElementById('password').value;
            if(passwd == 'passwordhere'){
                 window.location.href="home.html".fadeOut(1000);
            }
    }
</script>
```

Apparently it doesn't work and it may as well be completely wrong. Any pointer on what I may fix, or if it's completely trash, how should I go about building it?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Managed to make it work using this:

```
<form style="margin-top: 20%;margin-left: 40%" 
onsubmit="return check();" action="home.html" >
    <div class="inputcontent">
        <input type="password" id="password" />   
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <input type="submit" style="display: none"/>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    function check(){
        var passwd = document.getElementById("password").value;
            if (passwd == "melon"){
            return true;
            } else {
            return false;
           }
    }
</script>
```

Thanks to @Xenon for all your help.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: Bear in mind anyone can view source to get the password.

Comment: Yeah I know but for my purposes this isn't really a problem. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the problem:

The submit button was designed to be used in an HTML form. As you currently have it, there is no association between the password box and the submit button, and more importantly, **NO `<form>`**.

Try this instead:

```
<form onsubmit="myFunction();" action="home.html">
 <div class="inputcontent">
  <input type="password" id="password" />
 </div>
 <div class="buttons">
  <input type="submit" style="display: none" onclick="myFunction()" />
 </div>
</form>
<script>
 function myFunction(event) {
 var passwd = document.getElementById('password').value;
 if(passwd == 'password here'){
  // Do Nothing    

  // Onsubmit stops the form from switching the page to `action` (attribute on form)
  // But once the function exits, it goes to the page
  // If <form action=""> or `action` is not specified, then it will reload the current page (you might see a question mark), that's just the GET parameter

  // If your password is right, then we do NOT prevent the default action from occurring, 
  // So you go to home.html
 } else {
  // Makes sure you DONT go to home.html if your password is wrong
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I meant for the button to be not visible. As per onclick, I tried it before didn't work. Retried with your code, no hope either.

Comment: Still doesn't work. And I don't get it, it looks perfectly correct.

Comment: I tried adding an else just to see what happens: `else {
        alert('wadsa'); 
    }`    Diplays the message when incorrect and doesn't when correct, so it does work fine, just doesn't redirect. I tried replacing the URL to google or anything but didn't work. So now it's just narrowed down to why it wont redirect.

Comment: I see. You added a `.fadeOut(1000)` to the end of the `"home.html"` string. `fadeOut()` is not a function of `window.location`, or `String` (you called it on the string `"home.html"`) Try removing that

Comment: Did that, no luck. :(

Comment: This one redirects but no password control. It will redirect whatever you may have entered. EDIT: tried the alert-check again, it seems the else events, don't work.

Comment: Wooh, got it to work by changing the function to rather return a true/false value onsumbit to the action.   **EDIT --Code doesn't look very nice here does it? will Edit first post--**